# Javascript: clearTimeout seems to only suspend, not reset or clear?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to JS and am trying to modify the JavascriptKit jQuery-based megamenu system to delay showing the menu until the mouse has been hovering over the anchor object for a specified time.

The problem I am facing right now is that it seems that the clearTimeout that is called on mouseout only suspends the setTimeout, rather than canceling, clearing, resetting it.

At this point I am just showing an alert after a setTimeout call. Currently I have the timeout interval set to 2000 for testing.

As an example, since I have it set to 2 seconds delay right now, if I mouse over the object 4 times for 1/2 second, the 5th time I mouse over the object my test alert box appears instantly.

I thought clearTimeout was supposed to completely destroy the timed event. Why does it appear to only pause the countdown?

```
teststuff:function(){
    if(jkmegamenu.toggletest==1)
     {
         jkmegamenu.executetimedcommand()
         jkmegamenu.toggletest=0
     }
    else
     {
         //jkmegamenu.executetimedcommandcancel()
         clearTimeout(jkmegamenu.teststuff);
     }
    },

    executetimedcommand:function(){
        if(jkmegamenu.toggletest==1)
        {
            alert('abcde')
        }
    },

    canceltimedcommand:function(){
    clearTimeout(jkmegamenu.teststuff);
},
```

Comment: This is my first post here. Have found the code button. Will use it next time.

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it solves your problem (*cough*mine*cough*) :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clearTimeout` takes a timer id as a parameter, not a function reference.

for example, if you're setting a timeout for `jkmegamenu.teststuff`, you would do it like this

```
// set the delayed call
var timerID = setTimeout(jkmegamenu.teststuff, 2000);

// cancel it
clearTimeout(timerID);
timerID = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining "teststuff" as a function, and then passing it to `clearTimeout()`.  What you pass to `clearTimeout()` should the variable returned from `setTimeout()`.  If you're assigning the return value of `setTimeout()` to "teststuff", then you redfine it, you won't be able to pass the original value to `clearTimeout()`.